# Making autoconf search for C++ libraries

Tags: c++, autoconf

I'm writing my first configure.ac and need to search for a C++ library.

I tried the following line, but when run the configure script, it finds nothing.

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([xmlpp::Document::get_root_node], [xml++-2.6])
```

Probably something is wrong with it. So, how can I make autoconf look for C++ libraries? I don't want to supply a global method (and don't think libxml++ has one either).

Comment: Warning: Don't use autotools for new projects! This still isn't possible in standard autotools 8 years after it was asked. Correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289995/685984

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try [AX_CXX_CHECK_LIB](http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/guidod/ax_cxx_check_lib.html) from the [Autoconf macro archive](http://ac-archive.sf.net/). you should probably make sure that you either use `AC_LANG([C++])` or surround the call with `AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])` and `AC_LANG_POP([C++])`.

Comment: As an aside (and so, not part of my answer) many libraries support `pkg-config`, using the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro. I suggest reading the following from [Autotools Mythbuster](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/pkgconfig/index.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

This link is about finding a C-style signature function to the library so that it can be tested by autoconf or write your own test:

https://nerdland.net/2009/07/detecting-c-libraries-with-autotools/

Maybe worth to try, but I am getting an error with the AC_LANG_PROGRAM macro.  The problem is put -llibname before the foo.cpp file.  My compiler cares about the order of the -l and cpp file.  The linker will not be able to find the function in the library.

Answer (score -3):

Hope this helps. My suggestion would be to use CMake instead of Autoconf.

This CMakeLists.txt file should get you started:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module:FindLibXml2
find_package(libxml2 2.6 REQUIRED) # http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:find_package

include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR}) # http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:include_directories

add_executable(myApp main.cpp other.cpp) # http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_executable
target_link_libraries(myApp ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES}) # http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:target_link_libraries
```

To use the file, after adjusting for your project of course. Put it in your Source dir as CMakeLists.txt, then:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. # This is like autoconf and generates the make files
make
```

If it sounds intriguing check out the giant youtube vid on all the benefits: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ut9o4OdSC0

It's good to use CMake, CTest, CDash, and CPack together in a project.

Comment: CMake sucks, to be honest, but it sucks a lot less that Autoconf, which makes it a today's date autoconf replacement, so +1

Comment: Thank you, I'll also look into it as a possible choice.

Comment: actually what AC_SEARCH_LIB is doing is not done in your CMakefile, verifying that libxml++ contains the symbol xmlpp::Document::get_root_node

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the original question

Comment: It provides a solution to the ultimate goal; finding c++ libraries so you can compile. Perhaps changing from autoconf to cmake will be the thing that people googling this question need.

Comment: I've upvoted this, because it is the right answer. The poster said they are writing their first configure.ac, and the only answer to any question with this in it is to _not use autoconf if you can possibly avoid it!_ Never, never never use autotools for new projects! I have nearly 10 years experience with Autotools, listen to me, don't do it!!!!